# Iteratively pass one file from a collection of files as command line parameters in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file-io, command-line-arguments

I have *x* files: *A, B, C...* What I need to do is pass each of these files as the first command line argument to a python file and pass the others as the second command line argument until all files have been passed as $1 once. For example, on the first iteration *A* is $1 and *B,C...* is $2. On the second iteration, *B* is $1 and *A,C...* is $2. I've read about the *shift* command in shell but am not very sure if it will work in my case (I'm also relatively new to shell scripting). Also, is there a limit to the number of command line arguments I can pass to my python script? I would also like to create a variable to hold the list of file names before iterating through my files. Thank you!

Comment: There is no limit on the number of arguments, but there *is* an OS-imposed limit on the combined length of all the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has arrays, and supports array slicing via `${array[@]:start:end}` syntax, where *start* and *end* are optional indices. That's enough to get the job done.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the master list of file names in an array called $files.    
files=("$@")

for ((i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; ++i)); do
    # Store the single item in $file and the rest in an array $others.
    file=${files[i]}
    others=("${files[@]:0:i}" "${files[@]:i+1}")

    # Run command.py. Use ${others[*]} to concatenate all the file names into one long
    # string, and override $IFS so they're joined with commas.
    (IFS=','; command.py "${files[i]}" "${others[*]}")
done
```